# Howto create a const declaration using .NET Compiler Platform

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I'm trying to create a small code generator using Roslyn or as it is called now .NET Compiler Platform, prevously I worked with codedom, which was cumbersome but MSDN got a reference, now Roslyn has little documentation and all documentation is focused on code analysis instead of code generation.
So my question is simple:
How can I create something like:

```
private const string MyString = "This is my string";
```

using the Compiler Platform classes? I've found something like FieldDeclarationSyntax and ExpressionSyntax, but all samples I've found generate things like
    Myclass myvariable = new Myclass();
And there is nothing telling me something so simple as how to produce the
string type declaration.
any clue will be great.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) to easily figure out how to build different pieces of syntax. In this case you're wanting to add the `const` and `private` modifiers to a field declaration so it would look something like:

```
var constField = SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(
        SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)))
    .WithVariables(
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>(
            SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("MyString"))
            .WithInitializer(
                SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(
                    SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
                        SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                        SyntaxFactory.Literal("This is my string")))))))
.WithModifiers(
    SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
        new []{
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword),
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)}))))))
```

Comment: Thankyou this was what I wanted and thank you also for sharing the link to Roslyn Quoter!